# Resources on Topological Insulators, Dirac and Weyl semimetals

Tags: condensed-matter, resource-recommendations, semiconductor-physics, topological-insulators, weyl-semimetal

I want to start studying about topological insulators and go all the way up to Dirac and Weyl semi-metals. What are some good resources(preferable textbooks if there are any) that cover these(don't care If a resource does not cover all of these)?

**EDIT:** An answer on Topological Insulators was given so I am looking for an answer on Dirac and Weyl semimetal resources.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about full coverage but there are some review articles

- Qi, X., & Zhang, S. (2011). *Topological insulators and superconductors*. [Reviews of Modern Physics, 83(4), 1057–1110.](http://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.83.1057) / [arXiv:1008.2026](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.2026)
- Hasan, M. Z., & Kane, C. L. (2010). *Colloquium: Topological insulators*. [Reviews of Modern Physics, 82(4), 3045–3067](http://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.82.3045).

and some textbooks

- [Topological insulators and superconductors-Bernevig](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/10039.html)
- Shun-Qing Shen (2012). *Topological insulators. Dirac equation in condensed matters*. Springer.
- [Les Houches Summer School: Topological aspects of condensed matter physics.](http://topo-houches.pks.mpg.de)

plus many videos on YouTube by the above authors.

Comment: Bernevig's book is a good starting point but there are some notational inconsistencies as well as mistakes so be cautious.